# How to display two types of cells in UITableView without conflicts, but with the following requirement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, switch-statement

I have the following requirement to display data in a tableView as follows:

```
POST 
POST
POST
CHANNEL CHANNEL CHANNEL ...(Each row has 6 channels)
POST
POST
POST
CHANNEL CHANNEL CHANNEL .....
```

For clarification, see the below image:

[image]

For example, if posts count = 20 and channels count = 2

then we have to display like this:

```
POST
POST
POST
CHANNEL CHANNEL
POST
POST
....
```

Is it possible to implement this way in Objective- C using Switch statement or any other way without conflicts?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Add a scroll view that can be scrolled horizontally to the cells that are displaying the channels.

Comment: I will suggest collection view for this. With flow layout and giving appropriate size management of cells you can achieve this.And also if u want individual cell click call back it will be easy.

Comment: i think he does not want to scroll the channels horizontally? @Sathi Reddy

Comment: I implemented channels in pageViewController... The problem is that- code is not clear.. So how to implement it using switch case? Please provide some code.

Comment: I mean based on posts and channels count, how to write Switch cases..

Comment: Did the channel scroll in horizontally ?

Comment: Yes.. it scrolls horizontally..

Comment: Horizontally 6 channels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use CollectionView inside TableView. This means that you should have UITableviewCells to represent each posts and for channels you should have a UITableViewCell with CollectionView inside. This UITableViewCell cell will implement CollectionView Delegates.

---

For example, if posts count = 20 and channels count = 2

then you have to display like this:

```
POST - UITableViewCell
POST - UITableViewCell
POST - UITableViewCell
CHANNELS -> UITableViewCell ->
               [channel1 channel2] -> UICollectionViewCell 
POST - UITableViewCell
POST - UITableViewCell
```

---

```
UITableView[
     UITableViewCell -> Post UI
     UITableViewCell -> Post UI
     UITableViewCell -> Post UI
     UITableViewCell -> CollectionView[
                                         UICollectionViewCell ->Channel1 UI
                                         UICollectionViewCell ->Channel2 UI
                                        ]
]
```

---

You don't have to use switch case here. You need a property which is used to differentiate Posts and channels

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (data.type ==  DATA_TYPE_POST){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PostCellIdentifier];
        if(!cell){
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChannelCellIdentifier];
        if(!cell){
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChannelCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. Can u post sample code using switch case in cellForRowAtIndexPath of UITableView?

Comment: You don't have to use switch case here. You need a property which is used to differentiate Posts and channels. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. If possible, update your answer to explain-how to categorize a post type from channel type based on their counts..

Comment: it depends on the way you deal with the data. If you have a model you can easily add a new property and use it in this scenario.

Comment: Ok..i will try...